# React Native Sending Params to Server using axios

Tags: react-native-ios

I am new to React-Native

I have an issue with sending params to server in React-Native. I am using Axios for this. But when request is send to the server then I am getting error as described in catch block of the below code.
Please help me to fix this, I am attaching the response which I get from server.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Here my code is,

```
axios.post('Api Url',{
       params: {
        'email': 'annu@gmail.com',
        'firstName': 'annu',
        'lastName': 'priya',
        'password': '123456',
        'stateId': 1,
        'deviceInfo': deviceInfo 
       },
       headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'timezone': timeZone
      }
    }).then(async (response) => {
        const res = response.data;
        if (res.success) {
            try {
                // When Response is success then parse the response
                this.setState(res.result);
            } catch (e) {
                Alert.alert('First Error Error', 'Oops! Something happened. Please try again');
            }
        } else {
            Alert.alert('Second Error Error', 'Oops! Something happened. Please try again');
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        // throw('Error', err);
        // dispatch({type: err})
        Alert.alert(err);
        // Alert.alert('Third Error Error', 'Oops! Something happened. Please try again','err');
    });
```

The Response which I am getting is, I am attaching the screenshot of the response.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it myself. I was sending request in not proper way.
To send params to server we can do this in following way.

```
axios.post('Api Url',
  {
      'firstName': firstNameValue,
      'lastName': lastNameValue,
      'stateId': stateValue,
      'email': emailValue,
      'password': passwordValue,
      'deviceInfo': deviceInfo 
  },{
      "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
  }).then((response ) => {
     console.log("reactNativeDemo","response get details:"+response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log("axios error:",error);
  });
```

Using this you can send params to server in React-Native.